# Does $F_f$ (friction force) matter in an equation for jumping on the moon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Sorry if this should be asked elsewhere, and if it should be, please direct me as to where would be best to post it. I'm talking to a friend, who is basically claiming that Ff = µN would matter when jumping sideways on the moon. He was saying that a lateral jump sideways would be slowed down on the moon, due to friction being reduced on the moon (Friction force not the coefficient). 
I'm trying to tell him that any speed changes in a jump on the moon are due to the change in gravity and not due to Ff specifically. He's citing examples of jumping and skating on ice as examples. I've been telling him that lunar soil and earth soil probably have about the same friction coefficient, so bringing Ff into the discussion is nonsensical.

I understand that falling back to the lunar surface from a jumped height would be slower due to reduced lunar gravity. But would the friction force come into play in a jump *laterally* on the moon? I've been arguing with him that µ would be the same on earth as it would be on the moon (we both agree it would be). So I'm confused why he is referencing Ff, when a distance calculation wouldn't involve a different µ on the moon. Gravity would be different, but he's not been providing a calculation that involves Ff, so I'm at a loss as to why he's bringing up Ff into the topic at all. A jump laterally would not be slower side to side on the moon, would it? You would travel further, but the velocity would be the same, would it not? The drop down would be slower, due to reduced gravity, but wouldn't the lateral speed be the same on earth as on mars or the moon? you would jump further, (as you would fall slower), but your lateral jump velocity would be the same, correct? Or am I wrong?

Basically i understand that F=ma, and understand the math here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/79325/how-high-and-far-could-a-person-jump-in-lower-gravity

But my friend is basically arguing that Ff would matter in jumping on the moon, in that it would make lateral movement from a jump slower. I'm saying it won't. I can't find any equations that use Ff in a jumping scenario. How would Ff play into effect in a long jump/jumping on the moon? would it? I'm trying to tell him that Ff would only be different due to gravity being different, but that the lunar µ (of lunar soil) would be the same.

If you were jumping on the moon, the fall from the jump would be slower, but the distanced jumped would not be slower laterally, would it?

In what kind of calculation of a jump on the moon would Ff be a factor?? I'm telling him that it doesn't matter. Velocity would stay the same, acceleration might drop since distance would increase due to gravity being reduced (slower fall speed). wouldn't the calculations in my example be the ones being used? when would you need to involve friction? lunar friction wouldn't differ really, would it? it wouldn't slow down lateral velocity from a jump, would it? that's just gravity making the jump take longer because you travel further as you're not dropping to the ground at the same speed.